# What '...' indicates in function parameter in c?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, ellipsis, function-declaration

I was going through the logger code and came across a function

```
bool  LogMessage(const char *szFor, ...)
```

What does **...** indicates here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called an [ellipsis notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(computer_programming)#Variable_number_of_parameters). This means, the function is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

It can *legally* accept any number and type of incoming arguments.

Comment: Erm...what's wrong?